# Will a loop antenna work with only two turns?

Tags: rf, antenna, coil

I am considering the design of a manually-wound AM loop antenna roughly following [this guide](https://aa7ee.wordpress.com/2013/11/17/a-tuned-loop-antenna-for-the-am-broadcast-band/). It must be tunable in three ranges - 3.33MHz, 7.85 MHz and 14.67 MHz. The highest range would simply have a varicap in parallel with the antenna, and the lower two ranges will switch in a fixed capacitor to lower the resonant frequency.

The varicap with the widest range I have found so far is the [BB640](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/bb640series.pdf?folderId=db3a304313d846880113d98def1d0130&fileId=db3a304313d846880113d9d5b10c0172), tunable between 3.05-69pF, giving a geometric mean of C=14.507 pF.

The challenge is that given that kind of capacitance and 14.67 MHz, the antenna inductance needed is quite low. Following the widespread UMR EMC Lab formula adapted for a square antenna,

$$
n = 2 \text{ turns} \\
w = 100 \text{ cm} \\
r = 4 \text{ cm} \\
L = 8\times10^{-9} \cdot n^2 w
\left(
   \sqrt 2 - 2 +
   \ln \frac
   {4 w}
   {r (\sqrt 2 + 1)}
\right) \\
L \approx 10 \text{ uH} \\
C = \frac 1 {(2\pi \cdot 14.67\text{ MHz})^2 L} \\
C \approx 11.8\text{ pF}
$$

\$r\$ is the inter-turn spacing. \$w\$, the width (and height) of the winding frame, is large because the signal is expected to be weak. \$n\$ must be small because higher turn counts impractically increase the turn spacing. The needed \$C\$ seems close enough to the geometric mean of the varicap.

For the purposes of this exercise I'm disregarding the effect of impedance matching, but eventually the single varicap would be replaced with an impedance-matching network with an apparent capacitance that would resonate with the antenna.

Questions:

- Will high \$r\$ decrease performance by decreasing \$Q\$, or have other unwanted effects? Conversely, will it improve performance by decreasing inter-winding capacitance?
- With tuning capacitance values so low, will it be difficult to tune this circuit once parasitics rear their ugly head?
- Would it be practical or desired to decrease the effective tuning capacitance by adding a series capacitor so that \$L\$ can increase, allowing for more or closer loop turns?

Comment: *"Will a loop antenna work with only two turns?"* A normal loop antenna is just a single turn.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Not these - I've edited the question to include the guide link.

Comment: It would take 15 minutes to make that loop fairly accurately and then you can test it rather than expect a definitive answer here. Build and test is my advice. I think you'll be surprised (pleasantly) at the Q but dissapointed in your ability to keep it perfectly tuned.

Comment: @Andyaka Go to hardware store, get frame materials, measure everything, construct, test - yep, sounds like a good 15 minutes to me

Comment: Get a cardboard box that is roughly the size you want and wind 2 turns on it. It doesn't need to be centimetre accurate to get a feel for any parasitic problems. If necessary glue the wire to the box to test for drift problems. You could even wind it onto a plastic waste paper bin and not worry about it being square - get it about right and it'll yield numbers you need to know.